# Magento EE Set rewards Points

Tags: magento-enterprise, reward-points

In Magento Enterprise Version,How to set rewards points like below?

£1 spent will give you 3 Reward Points

- £200 spent = 600 Reward Points
- 600 Reward Points can be redeemed as £6 off a future order

.

- £300 spent = 900 Reward Points
- 900 Reward Points can be redeemed as £9 off a future order.

Please give me Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise reward rates defined in `Customers > Reward Exchange Rates` have a "direction" defined of either of two options:

- `Currency to points`
- `Points to currency`

Reading your requirements it looks like you need to define two rates:

- `Currency to points: 1 to 3`
- `Points to currency: 10 to 1`

Comment: Hi Bera,Thanks for your reply but our requirement is different it is like  "Spend Y Get X Reward Points"   .suppose that we have 100$ in our cart then rewards points should be add 300 and 101$ then 303 rewards points  means multiple of 3 of total cart.

Comment: Hi Bera,Can we set rewards points as per condition that If total order is above $60 and customer group is trade or student.Also rewards points not apply if cart have discount coupan?